# Remove class if display = none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to  add and remove class with the condition of CSS display. For example, I have some Div that can be hidden and shown. I want that, if the div is hidden with the `display:none;`, then the class of the div is removed.

But if the div is shown with the `display:block;`, I want to add a class to the div.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       if($('.bigPicture').css('display') == 'block')
            {$('.bigPicture').find('div').addClass('easyzoom easyzoom--overlay');};

       if($('.bigPicture').css('display') == 'none')
            {$('.bigPicture').find('div').removeClass('easyzoom easyzoom--overlay');}
  });
```

---

---

---

**EXPLANATION**

I have multiple slideshows in one pages. Not all of the slideshow is going to be shown in the page, one of them will only show if the link to that slideshow is clicked. It sames like auto hide and show function. If one slideshow is shown, then other slideshows are hidden.

Each slideshow has their own thumbnails to control them.

The problem is all of the slideshow has no ID and has the same class, while all the slideshow is run with the same script.

If the thumbnail in the second slideshow I click, the slideshow doesn't move. And I realize it slides only the first slideshow.

SO, the solution is I have to remove the class of the slideshow.

Comment: Display is not a css style... its a property.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Actually I have multiple slideshows in one page. And all of them has no ID and has the same class although they are shown one by one. I have to remove the class so that the slideshow can work to each div and not to all div.

Comment: And you can't target the element for the slideshow with "has this className but not display is none"?

Comment: check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/glegan/Cw2YJ/

Comment: Add a jsfiddle here, it might be easier to understand then...

Comment: @Glegan, thank you. but that's not what I am looking for now. If possible, please just help me out to edit my code because I am very sure what I am looking will work with that code if the code is arranged correctly..

Comment: @inandout you found the answer?

Comment: @Glegan, no. This is my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740462/the-second-slideshow-waiting-for-the-first-slideshow-to-finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are trying to do?

If so, it's easy to convert it to jquery syntax instead.

It would be easier if you had provided a jsFiddle of your problem.

CSS

```
.bigPicture {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.easyzoom {
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="bigPicture">
    <div>One</div>
</div>
<div class="bigPicture hidden">
    <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">Two</div>
</div>
<div class="bigPicture hidden">
    <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">Three</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('load', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.bigPicture'), function (bigPicture) {
        var div = bigPicture.querySelector('div:first-of-type');

        if (div) {
            if (window.getComputedStyle(bigPicture).display === 'none') {
                div.classList.remove('easyzoom', 'easyzoom--overlay');
            } else {
                div.classList.add('easyzoom', 'easyzoom--overlay');
            }
        }
    });
}, true);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kR9wC/)

Answer (score 2):

Try is visible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.bigPicture').is(':visible')){
        $('.bigPicture').find('div').addClass('easyzoom easyzoom--overlay');
    } else {
        $('.bigPicture').find('div').removeClass('easyzoom');
    }
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The class is still there even if the display is none.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is somewhat working. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmLgc/) where I have shown and hidden on the click of the buttons.

Code Snippet:

```
$(document).on('click','#addBigPicture',function(){
    $('.bigPicture').css('display','block');
    if($('.bigPicture').css('display') == 'block')
      {$('.bigPicture').find('div').addClass('easyzoom easyzoom--overlay');};
});

$(document).on('click','#hideBigPicture',function(){
    $('.bigPicture').css('display','none');
    if($('.bigPicture').css('display') == 'none')
         {$('.bigPicture').find('div').removeClass('easyzoom easyzoom--overlay');}
});
```

The if loops are as desired by you. Hope it helps!!